# Join data from two tables with fk

Tags: mysql, join

Hellow guys,

I have 2 tables like that :

```
users
id   name
============
1    Piter
2    Vladimir
3    Paul

data
id    creator   reviewer   text
===================================
1     1         2          bla1
2     1         3          bla2
3     2         3          bla3
```

In data table creator and reviewer have fk referenced to users.indexid.

Is there a way without multiple select (ie, by using join - this is the method now I am trying to use), to get data with name resolved.

example that is indeed not working

```
SELECT *
FROM data as d
LEFT JOIN users as u 
   ON d.creator = u.indexid
LEFT JOIN users as u2
  ON d.reviewer = u2.indexid 
WHERE data.id = 1
```

This want some results like :

```
results 
id   creator  reviewer  text
=============================
1    Piter    Vladimir  bla1
```

Instead, I get :

```
`bad_results`
id   creator  reviewer  text
=============================
1    1        2         bla1
```

Can someone point me where I fail ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - your 2nd join condition need to change like `d.reviewer = u2.indexid`

```
SELECT d.id,u.name as creator,u2.name as reviewer, text
FROM data as d
LEFT JOIN users as u 
   ON d.creator = u.indexid
LEFT JOIN users as u2
  ON d.reviewer = u2.indexid 
WHERE data.id = 1
```